# TrimEnd() not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to trim the end off a string if it ends in ", ". That's a comma and a space.

I've tried `TrimEnd(', ')`, but this doesn't work. It has to be only if the string ends this way, so I can't just use `.Remove` to remove the last two characters. How can I do it?

Comment: Strings are immutable. All string methods doesn't alter the string, but return new strings.

Comment: phil, what should happen with `"Bar "`, `"Bar,"` and `"Bar , "` ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
string txt = " testing, ,  ";
txt = txt.TrimEnd(',',' ');   // txt = "testing"
```

This uses [the overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `TrimEnd(params char[] trimChars)`. You can specify 1 or more chars that will form the set of chars to remove. In this case comma and space.

Comment: good, working for me on lable.trimend, but can you explain how it is working, what is difference in txt.TrimEnd(',',' ') vs txt.TrimEnd(',')

Comment: Edited. `TrimEnd(',')` would not remove spaces.

Answer (score 10):

This should work:

```
string s = "Bar, ";

if (s.EndsWith(", "))
    s = s.Substring(0, s.Length - 2);
```

**EDIT**

Come to think of it, this would make a nice extension method:

```
public static String RemoveSuffix(this string value, string suffix)
{
    if (value.EndsWith(suffix))
        return value.Substring(0, value.Length - suffix.Length);

    return value;
}
```

Comment: In principle this is the only correct answer so far, but there's a bug: You need to use either `source.Substring(0, source.Length - suffix.Length)` or `source.Remove(source.Length - suffix.Length)` etc.

Comment: @LukeH: you take the question very literally and it is indeed what the OP asked. But I can't imagine that "Bar ", "Bar," and "Bar , " should not be trimmed.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
string someText = "some text, ";
char[] charsToTrim = { ',', ' ' };
someText = someText.TrimEnd(charsToTrim);
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 4):

The catch is that `mystring.Trim(',')` will only work if you reassign it to the `string` itself like this:

```
mystring = mystring.Trim(',')
```

Comment: Please enclose code in backticks when posting answers so that it's more readable.

Answer (score 0):

`"value, ".Trim().TrimEnd(",")` should also work.

Answer (score -1):

```
 if (model != null && ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    var categoryCreate = new Categories
                    {
                        CategoryName = model.CategoryName.TrimStart().TrimEnd(),
                        Description = model.Description.TrimStart().TrimEnd()
                    };
                    _CategoriesService.Create(categoryCreate);
                }
```

TrimStart().TrimEnd() == Left Trim and Right Trim

Comment: This code does not trim the ','. Also why do you post an answer to a question over 5 years old that already has an accepted answer?