# String.TrimStart does not trim spurious spaces

Tags: c#, trim

Well, the title says it all. Reply, in this case, is outputting " This is a".
Is there a known bug with Trim?  My only thought here is that it is something to do with the fact that I am implementing `fnms` as a method, although I don't see a problem with that?

```
string nStr = " This is a test"

string fnms(string nStr)
{
    nStr.TrimStart(' ');  //doesn't trim the whitespace...
    nStr.TrimEnd(' ');
    string[] tokens = (nStr ?? "").Split(' ');
    string delim = "";
    string reply = null;
    for (int t = 0; t < tokens.Length - 1; t++)
    {
        reply += delim + tokens[t];
        delim = " ";
    }
    //reply.TrimStart(' ');        //It doesn't work here either, I tried.
    //reply.TrimEnd(' ');
    return reply;
}
```

Comment: You have to do nStr = nStr.TrimStart(), strings are immutable

Comment: Unrelated, but your `(nStr ?? "")` does not make sense. If `nStr == null`, `nStr.TrimStart(' ')` will throw a `NullReferenceException`,  so if you get to line three, you already know that `nStr` cannot be `null`.

Comment: @hvd Yes, you are correct. The only reason that it is formulated as such is because I have only just realised a need to implement it. However, prior to that I had the array creation as the first task in the method.

Comment: You can use `nStr = nStr.Trim();` to trim leading and trailing spaces at once.

Comment: @Sinatr I thought this would remove all whitespace altogether?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TrimEnd() not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521300/trimend-not-working)

Comment: @Wolfish, all **leading** and **trailing** [white-spaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace.aspx). Won't delete anything in between, aka you will received `"This is a test"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TrimStart` and `TrimEnd`, as well as every other method which acts to change a string *return* the changed string. They can never change the string in place due to string being [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

```
nStr = nStr.TrimStart(' ').TrimEnd(' ');
```

You can simplify this by just calling [`Trim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which trims the start and end of the string

```
nStr = nStr.Trim();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to update nStr to the returned sting from TrimStart, and then do the same for TrimEnd.

```
        nStr = nStr.TrimStart(' ');
        nStr = nStr.TrimEnd(' ');
        var tokens = (nStr ?? "").Split(' ');
        var delim = "";
        string reply = null;
        for (int t = 0; t < tokens.Length - 1; t++)
        {
            reply += delim + tokens[t];
            delim = " ";
        }
        //reply.TrimStart(' ');        //It doesn't work here either, I tried.
        //reply.TrimEnd(' ');
        return reply;
```